# Trying to do an assignment but stuck at ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Im doing a course on DB, this is one of the first assignments, I'm about to be done, but there is an issue somewhere in my `REL_CURSOS_ALUMNOS` query which ends up with the ORA-00906 error.

`REL_CURSOS_ALUMNOS` is a relationship table for "one to many"  1 ' `CURSOS(Id_Curso)` to many `ALUMNOS(NIF_Alumno)`.

This is my query till now:

```
CREATE TABLE PROFESORES(
  NIF_Profesor VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT Prof_NIF_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Nombre VARCHAR2(30),
  Apellido1 VARCHAR2(30),
  Apellido2 VARCHAR2(30),
  Direccion VARCHAR2(4000),
  Titulacion VARCHAR2(500),
  Salario FLOAT(10) CONSTRAINT Prof_sal_NN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS(
    NIF_Alumno VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT Alum_NIF_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR2(30),
    Apellido1 VARCHAR2(30),
    Apellido2 VARCHAR2(30),
    Direccion VARCHAR2(4000),
    Sexo CHAR(1),
    Fecha_Nacimiento DATE
    );

CREATE TABLE CURSOS (
    Id_Curso VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT Curs_Id_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR2(400) UNIQUE,
    NIF_Profesor VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES PROFESORES (NIF_Profesor),
    Max_Alumnos NUMBER(5),
    Inicio_Fecha DATE,
    Final_Fecha DATE,
    Num_Horas NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Curs_FechasIncorrectas CHECK (Final_Fecha > Inicio_Fecha));

CREATE TABLE REL_CURSOS_ALUMNOS (
  Id_Curso VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES CURSOS(Id_Cursos),
  NIF_Alumno VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES ALUMNOS(NIF_Alumno) CONSTRAINT RCA_NIFAlum_UQ UNIQUE,
UNIQUE KEY (Id_Curso, NIF_Alumno));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of small errors in the final table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE REL_CURSOS_ALUMNOS (
  Id_Curso VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES CURSOS(Id_Curso),
  NIF_Alumno VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES ALUMNOS(NIF_Alumno) CONSTRAINT RCA_NIFAlum_UQ UNIQUE,
  UNIQUE (Id_Curso, NIF_Alumno)
);
```

Your specific problem is caused by `KEY`.  That is not needed for a unique constraint definition.  Further, the reference for `CURSOS` is `id_curso`, not `id_cursos`.

I left both `unique` definitions.  But if `NIF_Alumno` is unique, then the pair `(Id_Curso, NIF_Alumno)` is also unique, so that constraint is redundant.